# matlab coordinates from data cursor

Tags: matlab, coordinates

I have created a surface of revolution in the following way:

```
r1=[-5:1:5];
r2=[1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1];
n=length(r2);
[rho,theta] = meshgrid(r1,linspace(0,2*pi,n));
X = rho.*cos(theta);
Y = rho.*sin(theta);
Z = repmat((r2/max(r2)),n,1);
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

I want to get the coordinates of all the points of the surface in the way that are displayed with the "data cursor". Is there a possible way to do this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The points in the grid are those you entered into X,Y,Z. Do you mean you wish to get other points on the surface? As in a higher resolution than what you entered in X,Y,Z? I don't think there is built-in interpolation in any type of plot.

Comment: No. I mean each point of the surface to be expressed in the form a(x,y,z) i.e. each z for the corresponding (x,y) and finally to have one matrix 11x11 with the values of z for each (x,y). In other words how matlab correlates Z with X and Y and makes a surface in the form Z=f(X,Y).

Comment: Your intention is unclear to me. Could you post an example of what you wish to get?

Comment: Is there a possible way to obtain a matrix where rows correspond to X, columns correspond to Y and the elements are Z?